# How to use multiple Tags with ESP32 UWB dw1000 for Indoor-Tracking?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, indoor-positioning-system

I am currently working on an indoor positioning system. For this I use an ESP32 UWB and "Arduino IDE" (--> including the library from Thomas Trojer: DW1000). The goal should be that multiple tags are localized. With one tag and two anchors the system works perfectly. But as soon as I use more than 1 tag, there is signal interference. Can you help me with this problem? Do you have a working code for such an indoor-positioning system?

Code for TAG:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "DW1000Ranging.h"

#define SPI_SCK 18
#define SPI_MISO 19
#define SPI_MOSI 23
#define DW_CS 4

// connection pins
const uint8_t PIN_RST = 27; // reset pin
const uint8_t PIN_IRQ = 34; // irq pin
const uint8_t PIN_SS = 4;   // spi select pin

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(1000);
    //init the configuration
    SPI.begin(SPI_SCK, SPI_MISO, SPI_MOSI);
    DW1000Ranging.initCommunication(PIN_RST, PIN_SS, PIN_IRQ); //Reset, CS, IRQ pin
    //define the sketch as anchor. It will be great to dynamically change the type of module
    DW1000Ranging.attachNewRange(newRange);
    DW1000Ranging.attachNewDevice(newDevice);
    DW1000Ranging.attachInactiveDevice(inactiveDevice);
    //Enable the filter to smooth the distance
    //DW1000Ranging.useRangeFilter(true);

    //we start the module as a tag
    DW1000Ranging.startAsTag("7F:00:22:EA:82:60:3B:9C", DW1000.MODE_LONGDATA_RANGE_LOWPOWER);
}

void loop()
{
    DW1000Ranging.loop();
}

void newRange()
{
    Serial.print("from: ");
    Serial.print(DW1000Ranging.getDistantDevice()->getShortAddress(), HEX);
    Serial.print("\t Range: ");
    Serial.print(DW1000Ranging.getDistantDevice()->getRange());
    Serial.print(" m");
    Serial.print("\t RX power: ");
    Serial.print(DW1000Ranging.getDistantDevice()->getRXPower());
    Serial.println(" dBm");
}

void newDevice(DW1000Device *device)
{
    Serial.print("ranging init; 1 device added ! -> ");
    Serial.print(" short:");
    Serial.println(device->getShortAddress(), HEX);
}

void inactiveDevice(DW1000Device *device)
{
    Serial.print("delete inactive device: ");
    Serial.println(device->getShortAddress(), HEX);
}
```

Code for Anchor:

```
 #include <SPI.h>
#include "DW1000Ranging.h"

#define ANCHOR_ADD "88:17:5B:D5:A9:9A:E2:9C"

#define SPI_SCK 18
#define SPI_MISO 19
#define SPI_MOSI 23
#define DW_CS 4

// connection pins
const uint8_t PIN_RST = 27; // reset pin
const uint8_t PIN_IRQ = 34; // irq pin
const uint8_t PIN_SS = 4;   // spi select pin

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(1000);
    //init the configuration
    SPI.begin(SPI_SCK, SPI_MISO, SPI_MOSI);
    DW1000Ranging.initCommunication(PIN_RST, PIN_SS, PIN_IRQ); //Reset, CS, IRQ pin
    //define the sketch as anchor. It will be great to dynamically change the type of module
    DW1000Ranging.attachNewRange(newRange);
    DW1000Ranging.attachBlinkDevice(newBlink);
    DW1000Ranging.attachInactiveDevice(inactiveDevice);
    //Enable the filter to smooth the distance
    //DW1000Ranging.useRangeFilter(true);

    //we start the module as an anchor
    // DW1000Ranging.startAsAnchor("82:17:5B:D5:A9:9A:E2:9C", DW1000.MODE_LONGDATA_RANGE_ACCURACY);

    DW1000Ranging.startAsAnchor(ANCHOR_ADD, DW1000.MODE_LONGDATA_RANGE_LOWPOWER, false);
    // DW1000Ranging.startAsAnchor(ANCHOR_ADD, DW1000.MODE_SHORTDATA_FAST_LOWPOWER);
    // DW1000Ranging.startAsAnchor(ANCHOR_ADD, DW1000.MODE_LONGDATA_FAST_LOWPOWER);
    // DW1000Ranging.startAsAnchor(ANCHOR_ADD, DW1000.MODE_SHORTDATA_FAST_ACCURACY);
    // DW1000Ranging.startAsAnchor(ANCHOR_ADD, DW1000.MODE_LONGDATA_FAST_ACCURACY);
    // DW1000Ranging.startAsAnchor(ANCHOR_ADD, DW1000.MODE_LONGDATA_RANGE_ACCURACY);
}

void loop()
{
    DW1000Ranging.loop();
}

void newRange()
{
    Serial.print("from: ");
    Serial.print(DW1000Ranging.getDistantDevice()->getShortAddress(), HEX);
    Serial.print("\t Range: ");
    Serial.print(DW1000Ranging.getDistantDevice()->getRange());
    Serial.print(" m");
    Serial.print("\t RX power: ");
    Serial.print(DW1000Ranging.getDistantDevice()->getRXPower());
    Serial.println(" dBm");
}

void newBlink(DW1000Device *device)
{
    Serial.print("blink; 1 device added ! -> ");
    Serial.print(" short:");
    Serial.println(device->getShortAddress(), HEX);
}

void inactiveDevice(DW1000Device *device)
{
    Serial.print("delete inactive device: ");
    Serial.println(device->getShortAddress(), HEX);
}
```